# Thymeleaf Resolver in Java Application, non a Java Web

Tags: java, templates, thymeleaf

Hello I've used Thymeleaf in Java Web Application with Spring without much problems, but I'm making a Java Application  (Java SE non a Java Web Application) and I have problems with Thymeleaf Template Resolver, which can't find my templates, and I think it can be possible because when I set a prefix of template resolver is from the root "/WEB-INF" (inside of WebContent folder),but in Java SE it doesn't exist,this is my code:

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
Context context = new Context(Locale.UK);
final String contentMessage = templateEngine.process("emailInvitations/invitation", context);
```

I get this error:

> Error resolving template "emailInvitations/invitation", template might
>   not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template
>   Resolvers

My folder templates is under project folder, but I've tried setting the prefix "classpath:/templates/" and moving templates folder under src folder.

There is any way to get this work with Java SE?
I am spanish, sorry if my english isn't perfect.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you upload a picture of your project structure ?

Comment: You need to place the templates directory in the src/resources directory

Answer (score 0):

Just change code :

```
resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
```

to

```
resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
```

for java application you don't have to start with "/"